# What should i give to my CNN? Large Input matrix or 10,000 small input matrices?

Tags: python, image-processing, matrix, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have an input data matrix of size (10000,784) meaning i have 10,000 images of 28x28 matrix. I reshaped the matrix

```
X_data=np.reshape(10000*28,28)
```

This makes the matrix size 280000x28. If i give this to my neural network

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(28,28,1)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))
```

i get the following error while fitting the model

*Error when checking input: expected conv2d_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (28000, 28)*

What am i doing wrong? Is my approach correct as i have a big matrix instead of 10000 small matrices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since i got the answer:

The reshape was not correct.

```
img = img.reshape((10000, 28, 28, 1))
```

Now i have 10000 images of size *28x28*